# Force-quit when external xlsm libraries are referenced and open

Tags: vba, excel

I have three files, one is `app.xlsm`, the other one is `lib.xlsm`, whereas `app.xlsm` uses `lib.xlsm` as a reference (which is specified in Tools -> References). The third, `third.xlsm` has the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    prompt = MsgBox("If you click Ok, Excel will force close." & vbCrLf & _
            "If you click Cancel, you can work with the file", vbOKCancel)
    If prompt = vbOK Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        thisworkbook.Close True
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Assume that I have `app` and `lib` open. Now when I open `third`, and then click OK at the prompt, `app` gets closed but `lib` remains open. I.e. Excel does not get force shut.

I need Excel to close all files without saving them and close silently.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you loop through the open workbooks in this instance, ie

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    prompt = MsgBox("If you click Ok, Excel will force close." & vbCrLf & _
            "If you click Cancel, you can work with the file", vbOKCancel)

    If prompt = vbOK Then
       For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
         If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then wb.Close False
       Next
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

*thermonuclear option to close all Excel instances*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Dim wb As Workbook
        prompt = MsgBox("If you click Ok, Excel will force close." & vbCrLf & _
                "If you click Cancel, you can work with the file", vbOKCancel)

        If prompt = vbOK Then
           For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
             If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then wb.Close False
           Next
        End If
        X2 = Shell("powershell.exe kill -processname excel", 1)
End Sub
```